# Rails 4 nil or empty argument with two forms creating new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I have two forms to create a new image. I want them both to go to the new_image_path but with the @image variable.

I get this error for the form_for lines:

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

One form:

```
<%= form_for @image, url: new_sm_image_path(@image) do |f| %>
```

The other:

```
<%= form_for @image, url: new_lrg_image_path(@image) do |f| %>
```

My Routes:

```
get "/sm_image", to: "images#new_sm", as: "new_sm_image"
get "/lrg_image", to: "images#new_lrg", as: "new_lrg_image"
```

My index.html.erb has two buttons:

```
<%= link_to 'sm_image', id: "new_button" do %>
<%= link_to 'lrg_image', id: "new_button" do %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `@image` instance variable in your Controller action's which are rendering these forms.
Currently `@image` is nil, so you are getting the error as `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`.

As per the comment,

`In my index.html.erb I have two buttons that link_to the get routes I posted`

you would need to set `@image` instance variable in two actions : `new_sm` and `new_lrg` as these are the actions rendering your views.

Comment: I already have @image set in my controller new(), Is there another method I should set, like new_sm_image() ?

Comment: What is the name of view rendering `One form` and `The other`?

Comment: One form: new_sm.html.erb in my views/images/  The other form: new_lrg.html.erb in my views/images/

Comment: Which action renders these views? Share the code of the Controller.

Comment: In my index.html.erb I have two buttons that link_to the get routes I posted